# Removing border bars of a chronosys period

Tags: timeline, chronosys

I'm using the [chronosys](https://ctan.org/pkg/chronosys?lang=en) package to create a frequency spectrum and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
\chronoperiodecoloralternation{red,blue,green,green}
\definechronoperiode{MyPeriod}[dates=false,arrow=false,textdepth=-60pt,textwidth=30pt,ifcolorbox=false]
\startchronology
[startyear=1,stopyear=20,startdate=false,stopdate=false]
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{1}{3}{Period 1}
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{3}{10}{Period 2}
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{10}{20}{Period 3}
\chronoMyPeriod[]{14}{17}{Description 1}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{1}{a}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{3}{b}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{10}{c}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{15}{d}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{18}{e}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{20}{f}
\stopchronology
```

Unfortunately, this code produces two "period borders" in my timeline right below the "Description 1" part. How to remove them?

**Edit:**

This is the resulting figure:
[image: Resulting timeframe with bars]

I would like to get rid of the two vertical bars before and after "d".

Comment: a handrawn sketch of the desired answer would be helpful

Comment: Please, can you edit your question putting a complete code and an image? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I just added an image for clarity.

Comment: I have a feeling that it was this feature of chronosys that caused me to abandon it and just use `tikz` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are hard-coded in the `\dochronoperiode` macro. You can patch them out using `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\catcode`\@=11%
\catcode`\!=11%
\xpatchcmd{\dochronoperiode}
  {\begingroup{%
     \dimen@i\dimexpr\!chrperiodtopheight-\!chrperiodbottomdepth\relax
     \!chrusecolor{\!chr!periodeschwarzodergr@u}%
     \kern-0.2pt\relax\vrule height\dimen@i width0.4pt\relax  \kern-0.2pt\relax
     \kern\dimen@\relax
     \kern-0.2pt\relax\vrule height\dimen@i width0.4pt\relax  \kern-0.2pt\relax
   \kern-\dimen@\relax}%
   \endgroup}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\catcode`\@=12%
\catcode`\!=12%
\begin{document}
\chronoperiodecoloralternation{red,blue,green,green}
\definechronoperiode{MyPeriod}[dates=false,arrow=false,textdepth=-60pt,textwidth=30pt,ifcolorbox=false]
\startchronology
[startyear=1,stopyear=20,startdate=false,stopdate=false]
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{1}{3}{Period 1}
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{3}{10}{Period 2}
\chronoperiode[dates=false]{10}{20}{Period 3}
\chronoMyPeriod[]{14}{17}{Description 1}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{1}{a}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{3}{b}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{10}{c}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{15}{d}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{18}{e}
\chronoevent[date=false,markdepth=-20pt,textwidth=2pt]{20}{f}
\stopchronology
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]